# Problem with Esbern in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I went to Riften during the main quest line, and found Esbern. However his dialogs have no voice at all and even if I can "talk" to him, he doesn't open the door. What can I do?

EDIT:

I am playing Skyrim Legendary Edition on PC.

Comment: Are you even on the quest to find him?  What quest are you trying to complete?

Comment: Unsure why the downvotes - what's wrong with the question? @Nelson He is trying to complete the quest [A Cornered Rat](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Cornered_Rat) and Ethan speaks of a genuine bug that has plagued the game since release. My answer provides a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue that *many* people have had since the game's release. Fortunately a kind modder over at the Nexus created a fix - this worked for me when I had the same issue: [Esbern Voice Fix by Firestar 0507](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/57163/?).

Just download and install with the mod manager.

Comment: As soon as I test this mod I'll let you know, thanks in advance